# Video is not rendering in full screen in webview once changing the device mode from portrait to landscape

Tags: android

I am playing the video from youtube in android webview. Once I am changing the device mode from portrait to landscape, it's not displaying in full screen, even I am setting the height and width of video view  at runtime according to device mode.

My code is:

WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);

```
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.test_webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);


    String summary = "<html><body style='background-color: rgb(38,38,38);'><video controls='' autoplay='' style='margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;' name='media' src=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqd491U4XEs></video></body></html>";

        mWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO. You should show us your code so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Set the WebView height and width in the xml file as

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```